# Android Workmanager: "You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest...."

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-appwidget

I use workmanager in appwidget with a separate process,

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".todo.calendar.appwidget.ScheduleWidgetSmall"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/schedule_widget_label"
            android:process=":widgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE_NORMAL" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE_WORKER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/schedule_app_widget_info_small" />
        </receiver>
```

```
    override fun onEnabled(context: Context?) {
        super.onEnabled(context)

        val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()
        val workRequest: PeriodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            ScheduleWidgetWorker::class.java,
            15 * 60 * 1000L
            , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()
   
        if (context != null) {
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(getWorkerName(), ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, workRequest)
        }
    }
```

but when add the appwidget to the screen， I got the error:

```
2023-06-07 14:58:42.145 30654-30654/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxx.xxx:widgetProvider, PID: 30654
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
```

**I don't disabled WorkManagerInitializer in manifest**

workmanager version: 2.7.0

when I delete the `android:process=":widgetProvider"`, the workmanager work well.

Comment: Its because `WorkManager` isn't available and initialized in that new process. You should use `androidx.work:work-multiprocess` artifact with `RemoteListenableWorker` or `RemoteCoroutineWorker`. See complete demo here: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/WorkManagerMultiprocessSample